Conditional expected value for exponential dsitribution
I'm meet with the following problem: A given  gas station two fuel pumps, $A$ and $B$, whose refilling time follow an exponential distribution with rates $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$, respectively. Both pumps are occupied and I'm next on the line, using whichever is freed first. I need to calculated the expected total time between entering the gas station and leaving it.
My strategy so far is the following: let $X_A$ and $X_B$ be the random variables for the time taken by each fuel pump. Let $D$ be the total time I'm in the gas station, then $D = D_1 + D_2$, which are the time spent till the first pump is free plus the time taken to fill my tank. Thus,
\begin{align*}
E(D) = E(D_1) + E(D_2) = E(min(X_A , X_B)) + E(D_2).
\end{align*}
The problem is that I don't know exactly how to tackle $E(D_2)$. I'm thinking of something along the lines of
\begin{align*}
E(D_2) = E(X_A \mid X_A < X_B)P(X_A < X_B) + E(X_B \mid X_B < X_A)P(X_B < X_A).
\end{align*}
But I'm struggling calculating it.
Am I in the right track?

I think you have a slight mistake (or I am misinterpreting the question). If $X_A < X_B$ (that is pump $A$ is free first) then $D_2$ is drawn from an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda_A$ but this random variable is not equal to $X_A$. For a given "realization" it will have a different value.

You have the right idea but it needs refinement.  Your waiting time for the next available pump is the minimum of $X_A$ and $X_B$, but the amount of time it takes for you to refill depends on which pump is free first.  For example, if pump $A$ is much, much faster than pump $B$, then your waiting time is going to be fairly short because $A$ is likely to become free first, but also, because if you use pump $A$, the time to fill is also going to be quick.
So I think a natural approach is to consider your total time $D$ conditioned on which pump is finished sooner; i.e., introduce an indicator variable $I = 1$ if $X_A \le X_B$ and $0$ otherwise.  Then $D \mid I = 1$ is going to be equal to $X_A + D_A$, where $D_A$ is the fill time with pump $A$.  Similarly, $D \mid I = 0$ is going to be $X_B + D_B$.
Then your expected total time is
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[D] &= \operatorname{E}[D \mid I = 1]\Pr[I = 1] + \operatorname{E}[D \mid I = 0]\Pr[I = 0] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[X_A + D_A \mid X_A \le X_B]\Pr[X_A \le X_B] + \operatorname{E}[X_B + D_B \mid X_A > X_B]\Pr[X_A > X_B].
\end{align}$$
First, we need to find $\Pr[X_A \le X_B]$.  This is just $$\int_{a=0}^\infty \int_{b = a}^\infty \lambda_A e^{-\lambda_A a} \lambda_B e^{-\lambda_B b} \, db \, da = \int_{a=0}^\infty \lambda_A e^{-\lambda_A a} e^{-\lambda_B a} \, da = \frac{\lambda_A}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B}.$$
In a similar vein,
$$\operatorname{E}[X_A \mid X_A \le X_B] = \frac{1}{\Pr[X_A \le X_B]} \int_{a=0}^\infty \int_{b = a}^\infty a \lambda_A e^{-\lambda_A a} \lambda_B e^{-\lambda_B b} \, db \, da = \frac{1}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B}.$$
Since $D_A$ is the fill time with pump $A$, we have
$$\operatorname{E}[D_A \mid X_A \le X_B] = \operatorname{E}[D_A] = \frac{1}{\lambda_A}.$$
All that remains is to put the pieces together:
$$\operatorname{E}[D] = \left(\frac{1}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B} + \frac{1}{\lambda_A}\right) \frac{\lambda_A}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B} + \left(\frac{1}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B} + \frac{1}{\lambda_B}\right) \frac{\lambda_B}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B} = \frac{3}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B}.$$

Thank you @heropup!  It is much clearer now. If you let me ask something, I see now that my approach would also yield the same result, that is $\frac{3}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B}$. So it means that at it was indeed right, even if not elaborated in a good way? I ask because I was unsure if setting $E(min(X_A, X_B))$ would indeed be right, since I was not conditioning it.

@ObadiahStane Yes, your approach is essentially correct.  The linearity of expectation means that you can proceed in the manner you propose--independence of $\min(X_A, X_B)$ and $D_2$ is not required.  I merely chose to apply this property at a later point in time, which is a little more cautious, because I wanted to be more illustrative in terms of the total time conditioned on which pump becomes free first.

The time you expect to be at the pumps is: the time expected until the first pump clears plus the time you expect to be at that pump.
$\quad\begin{align}\mathsf E(D) &= \mathsf E((X_A+\mathsf E(X_A))\,\mathbf 1_{(X_A<X_B)}+(X_B+\mathsf E(X_B))\,\mathbf 1_{(X_A\geqslant X_B)})\\[2ex] &=\int_0^\infty\int_0^b (a+\lambda_A^{-1})\lambda_A\lambda_B\,\mathrm e^{-a\lambda_A-b\lambda_B}\,\mathrm d a\,\mathrm d b+\int_0^\infty\int_0^a (b+\lambda_B^{-1})\lambda_A\lambda_B\,\mathrm e^{-a\lambda_A-b\lambda_B}\,\mathrm d b\,\mathrm d a\\[2ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$

For some reason we're not getting the same result and I'm not sure why.  I checked mine via simulation and it seems to be correct; e.g., for $\lambda_A = 1$ and $\lambda_B = 0.5$, we should have an expected total time of $3/(1.5) = 2$, but your answer gives $2/(1.5) = 4/3$.

,,,,  Hmm... I think I see where I may have goon awry.  Give me a bit.

Ah, yes.  It's the same pump, but the time you take is not constrained to be less than anything. So $$\mathsf E(D) = \mathsf E((X_A+\mathsf E(X_A))\mathbf 1_{X_A<X_B}+(X_B+\mathsf E(X_B))\mathbf 1_{X_A\geqslant X_B})$$
